# Vector member is lost while managing a queue of the class pointers C++

Tags: c++, class, pointers, vector, member

I have a very simple class called AClass with two members: an int and a vector of ints. In my program, I'm trying to use a queue of pointers to objects of that class and a while loop on that queue until it is empty. Within that while loop, I sometimes create new objects and add them to the queue for some processing. The problem I'm encountering is that the vector member seems to be lost for the objects created within that loop. The int member is accessible though. I can't quite figure out why...

Here's a small example of code that illustrates my problem.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <queue>
#include <string>


class AClass
{
public:
    int a_number;

    std::vector<int> a_vector;

    void print()
    {
        std::cout << "a number: " << a_number << std::endl;
        std::cout << "a vector: ";

        for (size_t i = 0; i < a_vector.size(); i++)
        {
            std::cout << a_vector[i] << "  ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
};


int main()
{
    std::queue <AClass*> aclass_pointers_queue;

    AClass first_aclass_object;
    first_aclass_object.a_number = 2;
    first_aclass_object.a_vector = { 1,2,3,4,5 };

    aclass_pointers_queue.push(&first_aclass_object);

    int some_break_condition = 1;

    while (!aclass_pointers_queue.empty())
    {
        AClass* current_class_object = aclass_pointers_queue.front();
        current_class_object->print();
        aclass_pointers_queue.pop();

        AClass another_aclass_object;
        another_aclass_object.a_number = 3;
        another_aclass_object.a_vector = { 5,4,3,2,1 };

        aclass_pointers_queue.push(&another_aclass_object);

        if (some_break_condition >= 2)
        {
            break;
        }
        some_break_condition++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Here's the output:

```
a number: 2
a vector: 1  2  3  4  5
a number: 3
a vector:
```

Nothing is printed out for the vector of the object created in the while loop. It's size is zero.

Comment: Why pointers? And to local variables no less..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the `while` loop, you are adding pointers to the queue, that point to the address of a local variable. In the next iteration of the loop, that variable dies, and the pointer that you have is no longer valid.

The first pointer that you add to the queue is the address of an object that lives for the duration of `main`, so that pointer is valid.

You *could* allocate memory for the pointers that you add to the queue. But you should prefer using something like `std::unique_ptr`, instead of raw pointers, if you choose to go that route.

Comment: Ah I see, I suspected it was a question of the variables going out of scope but the fact that I could access the correct int member was confusing. Also, regarding std::unique_ptr, this would allow the object it is pointing to to persist, but I would now be responsible for its deletion at some point. Is that correct?

Comment: @user1253514 UB can "appear to work" in simple cases

Comment: @user1253514 _"Also, regarding std::unique_ptr, this would allow the object it is pointing to to persist, but I would now be responsible for its deletion at some point. Is that correct?"_ No, consult some docs: `unique_ptr` will delete the thing for you when it goes out of scope

Comment: Accessing the `int` is UB as well, though it appears to work. And no, the whole point of `unique_ptr` is to avoid manually deleting anything.

Answer (score 1):

Your program exhibits Undefined Behavior due to dangling pointer to a local object which lifetime ends with the block that object created in (`while` loop in your case). Simplest solution in your case to store objects by value, rather than by pointer and let `std::queue` properly manage objects lifetime. In more complex scenarios (like you do not want to move/copy objects, or queue can contain the same object multiple times) you may consider to store dynamically allocated objects by smart pointers (shared or unique) in the queue itself or somewhere else so you would make sure that your queue does not contain dangling pointers.

Comment: Yes my goal was to avoid storing the objects by value as in my actual code, these objects can be relatively large.

Comment: @user1253514 storing them by value does not mandatory make it less effective, you are mistaken, but there could be other reasons to store them by a pointer (smart or not).